# WPF List Box Item Highlight color

Tags: wpf

I want to highlight an item in the WPF list box based on property value. I don't want to select the item using IsSelected = true because it will fire the selection changed event. When this property is set, I want that item to behave (visually) as if we are doing a mouse hover on that item.I tried setting the background color, through a trigger. But since we support different themes for my application, I don't want to hard code the back ground color as it doesn't sync with all the themes. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it based on property value, the easiest thing to do is to subclass list box item:

```
class HighlightItem : ListBoxItem
{
public bool IsHighlighted
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsHighlightedProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsHighlightedProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsHighlighted.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsHighlightedProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("IsHighlighted", typeof(bool), typeof(HighlightItem),
    new PropertyMetadata(false, (s, e) => 
    {
        HighlightItem item = (HighlightItem)s;
        item.Background = new SolidColorBrush(item.HighlightColor); 
    }));

public Color HighlightColor
{
    get { return (Color)GetValue(HighlightColorProperty); }
    set { SetValue(HighlightColorProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HighlightColor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty HighlightColorProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("HighlightColor", typeof(Color), typeof(HighlightItem), new PropertyMetadata(Colors.Red)); 
}
```

Then, in xaml:

```
        <ListBox >
            <ListBox.Items>
                <local:HighlightItem>item1</local:HighlightItem>
                <local:HighlightItem HighlightColor="Blue" IsHighlighted="True">item2</local:HighlightItem>
                <local:HighlightItem>item3</local:HighlightItem>
            </ListBox.Items>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.It still requires the color to be mentioned right? For eg you have given the HighlightColor = blue. What I am trying to do is when we set IsHighlighted="True" i want the item's background to reflect the selected item's background as per current theme, without firing the selection change event.

Comment: Unless the theme is doing something weird you should be able to simply use SystemColors.HighlightBrush instead of blue